# How to hide interfaces for MassTransit/RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using MassTransit with RabbitMQ. It works just fine.
However, I noticed that in RabbitMQ, for every Interface that the published message is implementing, an exchange will be created. This is not necessary and just clutters the RabbitMQ exchanges.

So, my question is: How do I avoid the creation of exchanges for these interfaces?
Is there some attribute that can take care of this?

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. MassTransit routing is based on types and without relying on types for exchanges and bindings, messages will not be properly delivered.